# how to find the string that is empty or null in many string and make the code looks clean

Tags: kotlin

I have several strings, like id, endPoint, etc, I want to do a check to make sure they are not empty or null, if is empty or null, throw an exception with the error message, eg: "id can not be empty or null"

This is what I'm doing now, but I need to check them one by one if the first if condition is correct, is there a way to make the code simple and easier?

```
if(id.isNullOrEmpty() ||environment.isNullOrEmpty() |endPoint.isNullOrEmpty() || description.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                if(id.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    throw IllegalStateException("id can not be empty or null")
                } else if(environment.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    throw IllegalStateException("environment can not be empty or null")
                }
                ....
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions like e.g. `requireNotNull()`:

```
requireNotNull(id) { "id can not be empty or null" }
requireNotNull(environment) { "environment can not be empty or null" }
```

There is no such function for checking emptiness, but you can easily create your own. You can also reuse the error message to make it shorter:

```
fun requireNotEmpty(value: String?, name: String) {
    require(!value.isNullOrEmpty()) { "$name can not be empty or null" }
}

requireNotEmpty(id, "id")
requireNotEmpty(environment, "environment")
```

Note that it throws `IllegalArgumentException` instead of `IllegalStateException` as it makes more sense in this case. If you prefer `IllegalStateException` then just rename everything from `require*` to `check*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a list to iterate them, but you'll lose name information for your error message.

```
require(
    listOf(id, environment, endPoint, description)
        .none { it.isNullOrEmpty }
) { "none of the items can be empty or null" }
```

If these are local variables and you need smart-casting so they are not-null after your check, then you can't iterate them, but using `require` at least makes it shorter.

```
require(!id.isNullOrEmpty()) { "id can't be null or empty" }
require(!environment.isNullOrEmpty()) { "environmentcan't be null or empty" }
//...
// They will now smart-cast to not-null if they were local variables
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you may use `require`/`check` functions for shorter code and the benefits of smart-casting.

But both original and suggested code suffers from incomplete error message - if several variables don't fulfill the requirement, error will be thrown only for the first one.

My suggestion:

```kotlin
require(!(id.isNullOrEmpty() || environment.isNullOrEmpty() || endPoint.isNullOrEmpty() || description.isNullOrEmpty())) {
    listOf("id" to id, "environment" to environment, "endPoint" to endPoint, "description" to description)
        .filter { it.second.isNullOrEmpty() }
        .joinToString { "${it.first} can not be empty or null" }
}
```